# Why does scanner.hasNextLine() hang?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When I try to use scanner.hasNextLine() on my program, it just sits there and hangs. I'm wondering if there is any way to solve this problem or any alternatives I can use.
EDIT: The reason behind this is so that I can remove everything from the scanner (the scanner will only have one line in it). So if there is a way to remove everything from a scanner, that would be easier.

Comment: How do you construct the scanner? What is your input source?

Comment: you need to put some code here.

Comment: Why do you need to remove everything?  scanner.close()?

Comment: uh... code?
if(in.hasNextLine())
in.nextLine();

Comment: And I construct my scanner by using a socket.getInputStream()

Comment: @ShawnShroyer It's best to just put a code snippet in your question, that is why you got downranked.  You didn't state that you are using `java.util.scanner` and we had to make assumptions to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this answer your question?
[StackOverFlow : why-does-hasnextline-never-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end)

If not, please put a sample of your code on here to get a more descriptive answer as to what your issue is. Most likely you are reading something that never ends. If you have a file or a string you should not have an issue but if you are reading in a constant stream of data it could potentially hang depending on how your code is written and what you read into the scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the api for `java.util.scanner` (as I assume that is the class you are using.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Note the `hasNextLine` doc:

Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner. **This method may block while waiting for input.** The scanner does not advance past any input.

(emphasis mine)

So if you have an open stream that is not closed, it will block till another line comes in, or the stream is closed.

Comment: Thanks for telling me something I know... So how do I fix it?

Comment: It's not broken.  It's working as intended.  The "fix" depends on what you want it to do.

Comment: @ShawnShroyer - You should work on improving your questions before downvoting answers for not giving you exactly what you want.