# Java JOptionPane.showMessage Dialog won't open

Tags: java, netbeans, joptionpane, messagebox

I can get a message box to open using the following line:`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name);`
but when I add a little more code before it:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("What is your name?");
            name = keyboard.nextLine();
```

I can no longer get the dialog box to pop up. The first print statement works correctly, but after I enter a name, the program just keeps running and doing nothing.

Here is my complete code using Netbeans, thanks!

```
package chapter2practice;

//Here I import classes
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/**
 *
 * @author Berley2001
 */

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
        //Here I create an object from the Scanner class
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        //Here I add a message from the JOptionPane class
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + name);
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end

Comment: Down at the bottom where it shows your program running with the green moving through the progress bar,(very bottom, right side) after I enter a name, that turns to a progress bar with blue (not moving) and it says 'running...' inside of that. It will stay frozen like that for several minutes until I end the program without the message box having popped up. Any ideas for why it isn't working for me? Thanks for your help!

Comment: the only case I can think of where that does not work is, when one forgets to Press the `ENTER` button, after typing a input .