# Java: String not printed

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

I am reading some data from a file and each line is assigned to one cell of the String array. For some reason when I try to print the array after reading the file(lines 8-10), I get nothing printed. When I print the line in the While loop(line 5) I get the line printed correctly.

```
    1: int count = 0;
    2: String[] s = new String[300];


    3: while(!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
    4:  s[count]=StdIn.readLine();
    5:  System.out.println(s[count]);
    6:  count++;
    7: }

    8:  for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
    9:   System.out.println(s[i]);
   10: }
```

Same code using Scanner:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int count = 0;
    String[] s = new String[300];


    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        s[count]=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s[count]);
        count++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: When the last line has been read, the in.hasNextLine() is not returning anything. It got stuck at the count++. See photo -> [DEBUGGER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7JBG.png)

Comment: I see nothing wrong, but without knowing what `StdIn` is or does, we can't see the full picture. Did you try **debugging**? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas added to my question the same code using Scanner if that helps.

Comment: Can you include in your question the exact output you're getting, and exactly what you want it to be?

Comment: You said you are reading text from file, but your edit suggest that you are reading from `System.in`. There is a big difference between both cases. System.in is opened until it will be closed explicitly so `hasNextLine` can't return `false` because user/process can be in the middle of writing to System.in so `hasNextLine` will need to *wait* for data so you are still in first loop. In case of file after it will read last line `hasNextLine` can return false and move on to next loop responsible for printing array content.

Comment: If you are really reading from file then post proper [mcve] otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: If you are not reading from file but from System.in then this is same problem as explained here: [Why does hasNextLine() never end?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5653338)

Answer (score -1):

This will only work with a file but when using `System.in` here the in.hasNextLine() never gives false. You need to provide it with a condition to break the while loop.

Comment: Ctrl+Z will end input, causing `hasNextLine()` to return false.

Answer (score -2):

```
8:  for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
```

here your error, this should be s.length instead of count

Comment: Not really, the count will store the same as `s.length()`

Comment: I used count because maybe not all the 300 indexes will be used

Comment: Yeah, and that's the correct way. But what Juan Pablo suggests might cause an Exception.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder `count` is not the same as `s.length`, because `s.length` is 300, and `count` is actual number of lines read.