# debugging when timeout in hackerrank

Tags: java, performance, stream, request, timeout

I am working on a problem in HackerRank but it seems that I'm missing an edge case when I'm running my code because it times out. The first test case works with my code!

```
962668800 60.5
962668801 61.5
962668802 62.5
962668803 63.5
962668804 64.5
962668805 65.5
962668806 66.5
962668807 67.5
962668808 68.5
962668809 69.5
962668810 70.5
962668860 71.5
```

Output:

```
2000-07-04T00:00:00Z 69.5
2000-07-04T00:00:00Z 70.5
```

[image]

My solution:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {    
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int curr_min = -1;
        // how many response times per minute
        int count = 0;
        String curr_date = null;

        // calculating 90th percentile vars
        double sum = 0.0;
        double sq_sum = 0.0;

        while (s.hasNextLine()){
            int request = s.nextInt();
            double response = s.nextDouble();

            // get date from seconds
            String updated_date = Instant.ofEpochSecond(request).toString();
            int m = Integer.parseInt(updated_date.substring(14,16)); // minute

            int diff = m-curr_min;

            // check to see if data only one minute apart
            if (diff == 1){
                // first time encountering data
                if (count == 0){
                    if ((response >= 0) && (response <=150 )){
                        curr_min = m;
                        curr_date = updated_date;
                        count = 1;
                        sum += response;
                        sq_sum += response*response;
                    }
                }else{
                    // calculate 90th percentile for past minute, update curr minute
                    double avg = sum/count;
                    double mean_sq = sq_sum/count;
                    double var = mean_sq - (avg*avg);
                    double std_dev = Math.sqrt(var);
                    double perc = avg + (1.282 * std_dev);
                    perc = Math.round(perc * 2) / 2.0;
                    System.out.println(curr_date + " " + round(perc,1));
                    if ((response >= 0) && (response <=150 )){
                        count = 1;
                        sum = response;
                        sq_sum = response * response;
                        curr_min = m;
                        curr_date = updated_date;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                // within the same minute
                if ((response >= 0) && (response <=150 )){
                    count++;
                    sum+= response;
                    sq_sum+= response * response;
                }
            }
        }

        // print out last value
        double a = sum/count;
        double m_sq = sq_sum/count;
        double v = m_sq - (a*a);
        double sd = Math.sqrt(v);
        double p = a + (1.282 * sd);
        p = Math.round(p * 2) / 2.0;
        curr_date = curr_date.replace(curr_date.substring(17,19), "00");
        System.out.println(curr_date + " " + round(p,1));
    } 

    // round response times to 1 decimal place
    private static double round (double value, int precision) {
        int scale = (int) Math.pow(10, precision);
        return (double) Math.round(value * scale) / scale;
    }
}
```

What could be a reason that I'm timing out when my first test case passes? I'm dynamically calculating all my info and not using any arrays to store the data.

Comment: I believe a timeout on Hackerrank usually means that you will need to write more efficient code so it can complete the same tasks in shorter time. So you will have to look into optimization (as it’s called). Without having looked at your code, in some cases this is best done in a complete rewrite with an algorithm with better execution time characteristics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does hasNextLine() never end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition for reading input is wrong. Perusing the documentation for [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), the [`hasNextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--) method is blocking if there is no next line:

> ```
> public boolean hasNextLine()
> ```
>
> > Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
> >     **This method may block while waiting for input**. The scanner does not
> >     advance past any input.

*Emphasis mine.*

---

So it seems your code is working fine, but it is waiting for more input when there isn't any.

Furthermore, please don't do this:

```
String updated_date = Instant.ofEpochSecond(request).toString();
int m = Integer.parseInt(updated_date.substring(14,16));
```

This is quite awful as java has an entire package ([java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) dedicated to managing time, and yet here you are manually extracting the minute field from a `String`.

Here is a better way to get the minute:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(request).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
int m = time.getMinute()
```