# Java Data Validation

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a data validator to confirm I have an integer, as well as an integer between 0 and 4. My current code gets stuck in the loop within the nested If Else statement and I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner ( System.in);
   int lives;
   lives = 0;
   boolean isNumber;
   do {
       System.out.println ( "How many lives do you currently have? (Max. 4): " );
       if ( in.hasNextInt() ) {
           lives = in.nextInt();
            if (lives > 4){
                System.out.println ( "Please try again. Number must be between 1 and 4" );
                isNumber = false;
                in.next ();
           }
           else {
           lives = in.nextInt();
           isNumber = true; 
           }
       }
       else {
           System.out.println ( "Please try again. Number must be between 1 and 4" );
           isNumber = false;
           in.next ();
       }
   }
   while (! (isNumber ) );
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Where is it stuck?

Comment: Is it all test cases that are resulting in infinite loops? When you put in 2, for example, what happens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end

Comment: The code will loop back and explain that the number is incorrect. If I input a string, it loops back and asks again. If I enter a number not between 0 & 4 the code loops back and asks again. If I enter a valid number the code stops and will not launch

Comment: Am researching into that question. I appreciate the link @Rohlex32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lives = 0;
    boolean isNumber = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("How many lives do you currently have? (Max. 4): ");
        if (in.hasNextLine()) { // when enter key has been hit
            try {
                lives = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
                if (lives < 1  || lives > 4) {
                    System.out.println("Please try again. Number must be between 1 and 4");
                    isNumber = false;
                } else {
                    isNumber = true;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                //Report your error here to the user
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                isNumber = false;
            }
        } 

    } while (!(isNumber));
```

Comment: Appreciate you going above and beyond to help me out today. Was bashing my head against a wall all last night and this morning trying to come up with a validator that would work. I don't really understand the catch exception method but at this point I'll use it and look into it more and learn it

Comment: you are welcome. Sometimes the user migth enter character on the console input that are not numeric and this is what the {try- catch} helps you to prevent

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [Why does hasNextLine() never end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end), and see if that in.hasNextLine() is the same for your in.hasNextInt()