# Hi! I am using java and somehow have infinite inputs when I want to terminate the loop when there is a blank input

Tags: java

I am using java and somehow have infinite inputs when I want to terminate the loop when there is a blank input 
here is my code: I hope someone can explain my error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main1{

   /*int i=0;*/

   private static Customer[] getCustomer(){
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];

      int i=0;
      while((scanner.hasNextLine())){
          customers[i++] = new Customer(i,scanner.nextDouble());
      }

      /*int j;

      for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
          customers[j] = new Customer(j,sc.nextDouble());*/

      return customers;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){

      int j;

      for(j=1;j < getCustomer().length;j++) {

          /*Customer[] customer = new Customer(getCustomer());*/

          System.out.println(getCustomer());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5653349/3959856

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNextLine` of the `Scanner` class was created for situations when the `Scanner` is created for finite input streams, like a file. And then it's used to check if the stream has ended, in which case the program should stop asking for input.

However, `System.in` (a.k.a `stdin`, a.k.a the console) is infinite in the sense there can always be new input, hence it always has a next line and `hasNextLine` returns `true` anytime.

The condition you need to check is simply whether or not the input itself equals to the empty string, meaning the user entered a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a new Scanner each time you call getCustomer). For that matter, since getCustomer() gets a list of customers, it should only be called once, outside the loop.

Your getCustomer() method should create a List instead of a fixed length array,and it should return that list. And as @neo says, just exit the input loop whenever the user inputs an empty line.

Then your loop in main() would iterate through the list and print the customers. Something like

```
for ( Customer c : customers ) {
   System.out.println( c );
}
```

This could also be done with a single statement using streams.

This, of course, assumes that Customer has a toString() override that returns the appropriate String to identify the Customer.