# Issue with Reading Multiline Input

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to take user input and modify it a bit, but ran into an issue when the user inputted multiple lines. To fix this I tried:

```
public static String getInput() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        System.out.println("Awaiting input...");

        if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Combining Input to One Line...");
            while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                //System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());
                //System.out.println("check");

                input.concat(sc.nextLine() + " ");

                //System.out.println(sc.hasNextLine());
                //System.out.println("check2");
                //System.out.println("check3");

            }
        }
        sc.close();
        return input;
    }
```

It seemed to work until it got to the last line of input, where(after debugging a little) it got stuck trying to read sc.hasNextLine(). However, this is very strange, because I put this exact same code in an online compiler, where it works just fine, except for the fact that the input needs to be beforehand. It doesn't wait until there is any input. I'm not very experienced in Java so I could use some help.

Comment: I do no see you taking an input after "awaiting input"

Comment: Unrelated note: `input.concat(...)` does nothing. It doesn't change the value of `input` if that's what you meant, because `String` in Java is immutable. It simply returns a concatenated value - but you are not assigning it to anything.

Comment: As to your question, I am not sure I understand. But do you mean that your program doesn't know that your last line is in fact your last line? If you give it a file, it knows its the last line because it sees the end of the file, but when you input from keyboard, you need to close the stream (ctrl-D or ctrl-Z) to achieve the same effect - but I don't know if that's what you actually meant.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i changed it to a StringBuilder and used append. I am not sure about the other part. Whenever there is an input that has multiple lines it does append them all into one line, until it gets to the last one. I am not sure why, but the entire loop just gets stuck and won't do anything until I stop the program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does hasNextLine() never end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the infinite loop is your problem, than it can be solved by sending a special `EOF` marker (`Ctrl-D` on Unix, usually `Ctrl-Z` on Windows).

Comment: I tried this a few times and it only seemed to work once. The other times when I pressed `Ctrl-Z` nothing happened.

Comment: Nevermind, it did work, my keyboard was acting up. Thanks!