# Input multiple lines using hasNextLine() is not working in the way that I expected it to

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to input multiple lines in java by using `hasNextline()` in the while loop.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println(lines)
}
```

The code is inside the main method. But the print method in the`while` loop doesn't print the last line of my input. Also, while loop doesn't seem to break.

What should I do to print whole lines of input and finally break the while loop and end the program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does hasNextLine() never end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653338/why-does-hasnextline-never-end)

Comment: @sittsering I can't help myself to find any right solution for my situation.

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--. You probably need something like `lines.get(lines.size()-1)`. (Or simply have a String variable inside the loop that stores the reference given by the `nextLine()` for both the `add()` and the `println()`.)

Comment: to break out of while-loop (press ctrl+z for windows and press enter). maybe a typo, missing `;`  at end of SOP

Comment: Thank all y'all for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer that explains why `hasNextLine()` might be giving "unexpected" result has been linked / given in a comment, instead of repeating the answer, I'm giving you two examples that *might* give you "expected" result. Whether any of them suits your needs really depends on what kind of input you need the program to deal with.

*Assuming* you want the loop to be broken by an empty line:

```
while (true) {
    String curLine = sc.nextLine();
    if (curLine.isEmpty())
        break;
    lines.add(curLine);
    System.out.println(curLine);
}
```

*Assuming* you want the loop to be broken by two consecutive empty lines:

```
while (true) {
    String curLine = sc.nextLine();
    int curSize = lines.size();
    String LastLine = curSize > 0 ? lines.get(curSize-1) : "";
    if (curLine.isEmpty() && LastLine.isEmpty())
        break;
    lines.add(curLine);
    System.out.println(curLine);
}
// lines.removeIf(e -> e.isEmpty());
```

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim() and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()